# delete files older than 10 days and store the deleted file details in another file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, script, shell-script

I want to delete directories and subdirectories older than 10 days.

Also, I want to store the deleted folder and file names, time details in another file.

So far my script is to delete directories, subdirectories, and file which is older than 10 days.

```
find /tmp/processed/* -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Could some one help to store the details in another file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple commands at the same time:

```sh
find /tmp/processed/* -type d -ctime +10 -print -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

You can use the information that [@Ix07](https://superuser.com/users/269373/lx07) posted in [their answer](https://superuser.com/a/1402647/990194):

```sh
find /tmp/processed/* -type d -ctime +10 -printf "%p %TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %TZ\n" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

You can redirect the output of this to a file.
Note, however, that this can give quite messy (unaligned) output when viewing. As such, I like to use the `column` command in combination with tabs in the `printf` format to 'tablify' the data:

```sh
find /tmp/processed/* -type d -ctime +10 -printf "%p\t%TY-%Tm-%Td\t%TH:%TM:%TS\t%TZ\n" -exec rm -rf {} \; | column -t
```

I tested the output of the above, and it looked like this for me:

```
/tmp/processed $ find * -type d -ctime +10 -printf "%p\t%TY-%Tm-%Td\t%TH:%TM:%TS\t%TZ\n" -exec rm -rf {} \; | column -t
bar  2019-02-07  20:35:15.8718172190  WAT
foo  2019-02-07  20:35:54.5638166540  WAT
```

Look at the [man page for `find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to know more (tip: Search in the man page for `-printf`).